# Zip folder in C#

Tags: c#, zip, directory, archive, compression

What is an example (simple code) of how to zip a folder in C#?

---

Update:

I do not see namespace `ICSharpCode`. I downloaded `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll` but I do not know where to copy that DLL file. What do I need to do to see this namespace?

And do you have link for that MSDN example for compress folder, because I read all MSDN but I couldn't find anything.

---

OK, but I need next information.

Where should I copy `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll` to see that namespace in Visual Studio?

Comment: (moved follow on "replies" into the question)

Comment: project -> Add reference -> select the library

Answer (score 160):

This answer changes with .NET 4.5. Creating a zip file [becomes incredibly easy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). No third-party libraries will be required.

```
string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Comment: This works great. Don't forget to add a reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem and a using statement for System.IO.Compression.

Comment: I cannot believe how simple this is. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have an error when using the original path and destination path are the same, so remember to use the destination path different to the original path.

Comment: @ThanhLD Yeah they didn't make it so you can put the `result.zip` inside the folder (i.e. `startPath`) unfortunately..

Answer (score 57):

From the [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) help file, http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/releases/

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
   zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary= true;  // utf-8
   zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX");
   zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G") ; 
   zip.Save(pathToSaveZipFile);
}
```

Comment: @JohnB This has since been deprecated

Comment: This is adding Content of directory. I want to include Main directory as well like here in zip i want ProhjectX also then in that its content?

Answer (score 22):

There's nothing in the BCL to do this for you, but there are two great libraries for .NET which do support the functionality.

- [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)
- [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip)

I've used both and can say that the two are very complete and have well-designed APIs, so it's mainly a matter of personal preference.

I'm not sure whether they explicitly support adding *Folders* rather than just individual files to zip files, but it should be quite easy to create something that recursively iterated over a directory and its sub-directories using the [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) and [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) classes.

Comment: DotNetZip supports adding a Directory to a zip file, via the ZipFile.AddDirectory() methods. It recurses through the directory.

Comment: You can add a folder using SharpZipLib simply by adding the folder name plus a slash (can't recall if it's forward or backward) to the zip entry name.

Comment: SharpZipLib has GPL license: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/10/25/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib.aspx

Comment: +1 for DotNetZip. The organisation I work for uses it extensively and it's great for all sorts of tasks.

Answer (score 19):

In .NET 4.5 the ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath); method does not cover a scenario where you wish to zip a number of files and sub-folders without having to put them within a folder. This is valid when you wish the unzip to put the files directly within the current folder.

This code worked for me:

```
public static class FileExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> AllFilesAndFolders(this DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        foreach (var f in dir.GetFiles())
            yield return f;
        foreach (var d in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            yield return d;
            foreach (var o in AllFilesAndFolders(d))
                yield return o;
        }
    }
}

void Test()
{
    DirectoryInfo from = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test");
    using (var zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"Test.zip", FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            foreach (var file in from.AllFilesAndFolders().OfType<FileInfo>())
            {
                var relPath = file.FullName.Substring(from.FullName.Length+1);
                ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, relPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Folders don't need to be "created" in the zip-archive. The second parameter "entryName" in CreateEntryFromFile should be a relative path, and when unpacking the zip-file the directories of the relative paths will be detected and created.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me out!  Not sure why it's not up voted more.  I referenced your answer here:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872218/using-net-ziparchive-to-zip-entire-directories-as-well-as-extra-info/36893955#36893955

Comment: @ShmilTheCat can you try to use the .CreateEntry method for the folders? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133626/creating-directories-in-a-ziparchive-c-sharp-net-4-5

Answer (score 6):

There is a ZipPackage class in the System.IO.Packaging namespace which is built into .NET 3, 3.5, and 4.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx

Here is an example how to use it.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/ZipUnZipTool.aspx?display=Print

Answer (score 4):

There's an article over on [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DotNetZip/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Console%20Example&referringTitle=Home) that has a sample application for zipping and unzipping files and folders purely in C#. I've been using some of the classes in that successfully for a long time. The code is released under the Microsoft Permissive License, if you need to know that sort of thing.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Cheeso for pointing out that I'm a bit behind the times. The MSDN example I pointed to is in fact using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) and is really very fully-featured these days. Based on my experience of a previous version of this I'd happily recommend it.

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) is also quite a mature library and is highly rated by people, and is available under the GPL license. It really depends on your zipping needs and how you view the license terms for each of them.

Rich

Comment: The example code on MSDN uses DotNetZip, a free zip library that supports compression levels and encryption (including AES encryption), though the specific sample you cited does not show that.  The library produces "proper" zip files.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I'm still using the original version from a few years ago which was just a stand-alone code sample, so it looks like they've done a lot more work on it.

Comment: My apologies to Cheeso, as it looks like you are the admin if not the author of the DotNetZip library! It's proved very useful to me, even in its early form from when I first encountered it. :)

Comment: Edited based on Cheeso's comment.

Answer (score 2):

using DotNetZip (available as nuget package):

```
public void Zip(string source, string destination)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile
    {
        CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.BestCompression
    })
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(source, "*",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories).
            Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f).
                ToLowerInvariant() != ".zip").ToArray();

        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            zip.AddFile(f, GetCleanFolderName(source, f));
        }

        var destinationFilename = destination;

        if (Directory.Exists(destination) && !destination.EndsWith(".zip"))
        {
            destinationFilename += $"\\{new DirectoryInfo(source).Name}-{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-ffffff}.zip";
        }

        zip.Save(destinationFilename);
    }
}

private string GetCleanFolderName(string source, string filepath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filepath))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var result = filepath.Substring(source.Length);

    if (result.StartsWith("\\"))
    {
        result = result.Substring(1);
    }

    result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - new FileInfo(filepath).Name.Length);

    return result;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Zip(@"c:\somefolder\subfolder\source", @"c:\somefolder2\subfolder2\dest");
```

**Or**

```
Zip(@"c:\somefolder\subfolder\source", @"c:\somefolder2\subfolder2\dest\output.zip");
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code uses a third-party [ZIP component from Rebex](http://www.rebex.net/zip.net/):

```
// add content of the local directory C:\Data\  
// to the root directory in the ZIP archive
// (ZIP archive C:\archive.zip doesn't have to exist) 
Rebex.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Add(@"C:\archive.zip", @"C:\Data\*", "");
```

Or if you want to add more folders without need to open and close archive multiple times:

```
using Rebex.IO.Compression;
...

// open the ZIP archive from an existing file 
ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(@"C:\archive.zip", ArchiveOpenMode.OpenOrCreate);

// add first folder
zip.Add(@"c:\first\folder\*","\first\folder");

// add second folder
zip.Add(@"c:\second\folder\*","\second\folder");

// close the archive 
zip.Close(ArchiveSaveAction.Auto);
```

You can [download the ZIP component here](http://www.rebex.net/zip.net/download.aspx).

Using a free, LGPL licensed [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) is a common alternative.

Disclaimer: I work for Rebex

Answer (score 0):

`"Where should I copy ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll to see that namespace in Visual Studio?"`

You need to add the dll file as a reference in your project. Right click on References in the Solution Explorer->Add Reference->Browse and then select the dll.

Finally you'll need to add it as a using statement in whatever files you want to use it in.

Answer (score 0):

[ComponentPro ZIP](http://www.componentpro.com/zip.net/) can help you achieve that task. The following code snippet compress files and dirs in a folder. You can use wilcard mask as well.

```
using ComponentPro.Compression;
using ComponentPro.IO;

...

// Create a new instance.
Zip zip = new Zip();
// Create a new zip file.
zip.Create("test.zip");

zip.Add(@"D:\Temp\Abc"); // Add entire D:\Temp\Abc folder to the archive.

// Add all files and subdirectories from 'c:\test' to the archive.
zip.AddFiles(@"c:\test");
// Add all files and subdirectories from 'c:\my folder' to the archive.
zip.AddFiles(@"c:\my folder", "");
// Add all files and subdirectories from 'c:\my folder' to '22' folder within the archive.
zip.AddFiles(@"c:\my folder2", "22");
// Add all .dat files from 'c:\my folder' to '22' folder within the archive.
zip.AddFiles(@"c:\my folder2", "22", "*.dat");
// Or simply use this to add all .dat files from 'c:\my folder' to '22' folder within the archive.
zip.AddFiles(@"c:\my folder2\*.dat", "22");
// Add *.dat and *.exe files from 'c:\my folder' to '22' folder within the archive.
zip.AddFiles(@"c:\my folder2\*.dat;*.exe", "22");

TransferOptions opt = new TransferOptions();
// Donot add empty directories.
opt.CreateEmptyDirectories = false;
zip.AddFiles(@"c:\abc", "/", opt);

// Close the zip file.
zip.Close();
```

http://www.componentpro.com/doc/zip has more examples

Comment: FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen software. TY