# How to zip a folder recursively?

Tags: c#, zip, compression, dotnetzip

[I found this other question where Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905654/zip-folder-in-c/905735#905735) show a simple way to zip a folder. However this method doesn't seem to include sub-folders.

Is there some property or parameter that I have to set so it will also include sub-folders and all files in it? Or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ZipFile.AddDirectory` works recursively i.e. it would add sub-folders. Check the documentation: http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/3d01a0e2-c96e-f135-a78a-3668aefeda43.htm

Comment: Actually it was my mistake, I had two directories with the same name and didn't notice I was picking the wrong one. I'm accepting your answer as it shows the reference to the documentation where it states it is recursive. Thanks for the link.