# Zipping Folders in C#

Tags: c#

```
 Can any one have the idea how to zip folders (including sub files and folders like winrar doing) using C#...?
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Zip folder in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905654/zip-folder-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick google I found this: [SharpZipLib](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) (From the site: #ziplib (SharpZipLib, formerly NZipLib) is a Zip, GZip, Tar and BZip2 library written entirely in C# for the .NET platform.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty nice general .NET utility for handling zip-related actions and files. 
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

An example of usage, pasted from the website link I just provided:

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
     // add the report into a different directory in the archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
     zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
     zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
 }
```