# Zipping Directory using zlib

Tags: c#, zlib, compression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zip folder in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905654/zip-folder-in-c-sharp)

can i compress directory using zlib in C#
i know that we use ZOutputStream and ZInputStream to compress and decompress but it takes filestreams how i can make it to use directory

Comment: Do you have to use zLib?

Comment: yes i do because i compress in pc and decompress in mobile and it works great in that

Comment: my question not duplicate and i asked specific Question

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question specifically asks about using `zlib` to compress and decompress a directory while the linked question contains code for other zip libraries.