# How to zip all files in folder

Tags: c#, zip

I have a folder `"D:\folder"` and in this folder I have 10 files that I need to zip into a new archive `"D:\folder.zip"`.

Currently I'm using **ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib** but this is not a mandatory requirement, so other solutions are acceptable.

The problem I'm facing is that when I try to execute the method `FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"D:\folder")` I get an error because of access to the specifided path.

How can I zip these files in a simple way?

Comment: A quick google search: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37887/C-Zip-Files-and-or-Folders - Perhaps it could help you.

Comment: See [how to read all files inside particular folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840443/how-to-read-all-files-inside-particular-folder).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zip folder in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905654/zip-folder-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is much easier to use than SharpZipLib, example of zipping all files in folder :

```
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX", "ProjectX");
    zip.Save(zipFileToCreate);
  }
```

This is a an example from this page :

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples

Comment: Yep, this is a much easier library to use than SharpLib, +1

Comment: thanks! can you say me which assembly needs for this ZipFile. Ionic.Zip - as far as I understand. correct?

Comment: when i use this method zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX", "ProjectX"); I get archive with a folder. how can I make archive that will contain only my files from source folder? thanks!

Comment: leave second parameter empty: zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX", "");

Answer (score 19):

I also agree with the suggestion of Antonio Bakula to use DotNetZip instead of SharpZipLib.

.NET 4.5 includes the new [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28VS.110%29.aspx) and [`ZipFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28VS.110%29.aspx) classes for manipulating .zip files. With this support what you are trying to do is accomplished by:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"D:\Folder", @"Folder.zip");
```

---

As a side note the reason you get the error is because you're trying to open a directory instead of a file. The `File.OpenRead` is used to open a file for read, since you provide a directory, you get the error. If you want to enumerate the files or directories inside a specific folder you can instead use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` or `Directory.EnumerateDirectories`.