# Zip files in a folder using c# and return response

Tags: c#

I want to zip files and folders in a folder using c# and I've checked previously asked questions but they don't work for me...i'm currently trying to work with DotNetZip. Here's a bit of my code:

```
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\T1132\Desktop\logs");
            // add all those files to the logs folder in the zip file
            zip.AddFiles(files, "logs");
            zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
            var a = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
            zip.Save(@"C:\Users\T1132\Desktop\logs\Archiver.zip");
            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(f);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f + "will be deleted");
            }
        }
```

the code above works but it only zips the files and leaves the folders. Kindly assist me please, Thanks.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10643602/4685428)

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve] on how to ask good questions. What concrete issues are you experiencing with DotNetZip? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to zip files using DotNetZip.

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("big5"); // chinese
    zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX");
    zip.Save(ZipFileToCreate);
}
```

Above zips a directory. For more uses you can follow the links

https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples

or

http://grapevine.dyndns-ip.com/download/authentec/download/dotnetzip/examples.htm

Thanks

Comment: Thanks this is going good so far but i want a response to pop-up on the console applications screen, any ideas?

Comment: what you want on console?

Comment: I want a response specifying if it was successful or not

Comment: You can put a check at the end of your zip code. To check either zip file exist or not at that location, you have given before zipping. if exist then return true on your console else return false.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and it is working great. Make sure directory has enough permission(s).

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zipPath, path + strFileName + ".zip");
```

Comment: i've got it now, Thanks for the help mate @summerGhost

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
 string zipFileName=  "zip full path with extension";
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(" directory path");
        Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile();
        foreach(var file in files) {
            zip.AddFile(file);
        }
        zip.Save(zipFileName);
```