# C# ZipFile: zip only the contents of a folder

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I am zipping a directory in C# using [ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh485721%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
private void createZIP()
{
    string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
    string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath,  CompressionLevel.Fastest, true); 
}
```

It's working in general, but I just want the content of the /start/ folder in the zip file, not the directory itself.

Now:

```
result.zip
--start
---- file1.txt
---- file2.txt
```

How I want it:

```
result.zip
-- file1.txt
-- file2.txt
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last parameter to `ZIPFile.CreateFromDirectory`, for which you are passing the value true, determines whether the directory itself should be included as the root of the ZIP.  If you change this to false it should work as you desire.

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath,  CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
```

Comment: Oh, ma bad. I skipped that part in the documentation. Thanks, it works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend functionality beyond simple zipping to conditional zipping

use following link part[Adding or Removing Files from an Existing Zip File]

[Creating-Zip-Files-Easily-in-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381661/Creating-Zip-Files-Easily-in-NET)

and to create empty directory use following link

[creating-directories-in-a-ziparchive-c-sharp-net-4-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133626/creating-directories-in-a-ziparchive-c-sharp-net-4-5)