# Can I maintain directory structure when zipping file?

Tags: c#, .net, zip, directoryinfo

I'm attempting to zip up a handful of files but these files could exist in different directories. The zipping portion is working correctly but I cannot figure out how to get it to preserve the directory structure within the zip file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void CreateZipFile(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, string archiveName)
{
  using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(archiveName))
  using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
  {
    foreach (var item in files)
    {
      archive.CreateEntryFromFile(item.FullName, item.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133626/creating-directories-in-a-ziparchive-c-sharp-net-4-5

Comment: @Flydog57 thank you for the response. Those are about adding all files in a directory. I am adding individual files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Directories in a ZipArchive C# .Net 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133626/creating-directories-in-a-ziparchive-c-sharp-net-4-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ErocM the link provided by @Flydog57 gives you exactly what you want. You are not exploiting the `entryName` argument correctly (the second argument in your case when calling `CreateEntryFromFile`).

Independently of which file you are adding to the archive (from same of different folders), you have to structure your archive using the `entryName` argument the C# api gives to you.

If your file's fullname is `/tmp/myfile.txt`, and you do `archive.CreateEntryFromFile(item.FullName, item.Name)`, then the archive entry name will be `myfile.txt`. No folder created as the entry name doesn't contain folder structure in it's name.

However, if you call `archive.CreateEntryFromFile(item.FullName, item.FullName)`, you will then have you file folder structure into the archive.

You can try with your function just changing `item.Name` into `item.FullName`.

Just be careful, on windows; if you path is `C:\tmp\myfile.txt` for instance, the archive will not be extractable correctly. You can then add some little code to remove `C:` from the full name of your files.

Some examples taking your implementation:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo(@"/tmp/test1.txt");
            FileInfo f2 = new FileInfo(@"/tmp/testdir/test2.txt");

            List<FileInfo> files = new();
            files.Add(f1);
            files.Add(f2);

            CreateZipFile(files, @"/tmp/archive.zip");

        }

        public static void CreateZipFile(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, string archiveName)
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(archiveName))
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                foreach (var item in files)
                {
                    // Here for instance, I put all files in the input list in the same directory, without checking from where they are in the host file system.
                    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(item.FullName, $"mydir/{item.Name}", CompressionLevel.Optimal);

                    // Here, I am just using the actual full path of the file. Be careful on windows with the disk name prefix (C:, D:, etc...).
                    // archive.CreateEntryFromFile(item.FullName, item.FullName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```