# C# ZipFile - create empty directories

Tags: c#, compression, .net-7.0, system.io.compression.zipfile

I am currently trying to create zipfiles using System.IO.COmpression.ZipFile, which basically works by enumerating all files using Directory.GetFiles and then using CreateEntryFromFile to add them to my archive.

However, this fails when I have a folder structure with empty folders, i.e. folders that do not contain any files, but which I need in my target zipfile.

So I tried to additionally Enumerate all directories using Directory.GetDirectories and adding them using ZipFile.CreateEntry. However, this fails because this creates a file inside the ZIP archive containig the name of the directory.

So what is a good way to actually add empty directories to a zipfile?

Here is some sample code:

```
    using var archive = ZipFile.Open(tempfileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
    var rootPath = path;
    string[] dirs;
    dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);           
    foreach (var element in dirs)
    {
        string filePath = element;
        var len = rootPath.Length;
        var shortlen = filePath.Length - len;

        //will return a path without the rootPath is "C:\Temp" and there exists a folder "C:\temp\emptydir", shortPath would be "emptydir"
        var shortPath = filePath.Substring(len, shortlen); 

        //this line will create an element namend "emptydir" in the zipfile which is not a directory
        archive.CreateEntry(shortPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    }
```

Note: this is not a duplicate to [Creating Directories in a ZipArchive C# .Net 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133626/creating-directories-in-a-ziparchive-c-sharp-net-4-5) because System.IO.COmpression.ZipFile in .NET7 does not offer a method called "CreateEntryFromDirectory" in order to explicitly create a directory