# c# move files to zip folder?

Tags: c#, file-io, zip

What I want to do is create a zip folder by right-clicking in windows explorer, and new -> Compressed (zip) folder.

Then I want to use something like My.Computer.Filesystem.MoveFile("C:\From.jpg", "C:\ZipFolder.zip\To.jpg", true)

But I get an error "file or directory with the same name already exists".

Is there an easy way to do this? I thought windows supported zip folders but it seems to have no idea that I'm trying to move the file to a zip folder, rather, it is seeing the zip as a file and thinks I'm overwriting it or something.

Comment: Side note: Windows never supported "zip folders" - there is file system level compression and creation of Zip files/opening of ZIP files in explorer to see content...

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, at least provide the link to where it was answered before.

Comment: If you don't see automatic "This question already has an answer here:" comment in your post please ask question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com why it did not show up for you. Here is the link just in case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905654/zip-folder-in-c-sharp.

Answer (score 1):

In [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), adding files to an existing zip is really simple and reliable.

DotNetZip is a FAST, FREE class library and toolset for manipulating zip files. Use VB, C# or any .NET language to easily create, extract, or update zip files.

DotNetZip is the best open-source ZIP library for .NET.

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(nameOfExistingZip))
{
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zip.AddFile(additionalFileToAdd);
    zip.Save();
}
```

If you want to specify a directory path for that new file, then use a different overload for AddFile().

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(nameOfExistingZip))
{
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zip.AddFile(additionalFileToAdd, "directory\\For\\The\\Added\\File");
    zip.Save();
}
```

If you want to add a set of files, use AddFiles().

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(nameOfExistingZip))
{
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zip.AddFiles(listOfFilesToAdd, "directory\\For\\The\\Added\\Files");
    zip.Save();
}
```